# Any introduction to Teichmuller Space of $T^2$?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, gt.geometric-topology, reference-request

Is there any well written introduction for the modular space of complex structures on $T^2$?

Comment: If you mean moduli space, then aren't the complex structures on the 2-torus known and parametrized? (Disclaimer: I am not a geometer, so might be missing something here.)

Comment: Yes, I know it known, but I need a good reference to understand. I think is upper half plane/ SL(2,Z) action.

Comment: @jc: I think your comment is more appropriate as an answer.  There is no obligation to make an answer to a reference request long or deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, I'm promoting this comment to an answer:

McKean and Moll's book "Elliptic curves" is a basic introduction to 2-tori with complex structure from the function theoretic, geometric, and arithmetic perspectives. What's closest to what you want is discussed in section 2.6 (on moduli of elliptic curves) and chapter 4 (on the modular group).

Answer (score 2):

Serre's "A course in arithmetic" is quite nice for this and everything else it covers.